# How bad is using underscore in names?

Tags: haskell

I am mainly a C programmer. In my world, writing `likeThis` or `like_this` is just a matter of style. In Haskell however, it seems that camelCase is the definite choice. Personally, I find the later much more readable. Think `pthread_mutexattr_init` vs `PthreadMutexAttrInit`.

What's more, I have configured vim to swap the numbers and their alternate symbols (in C), since numbers happen to be written much less frequently than symbols such as parentheses, star, ampersand etc, which makes life easier on my wrist. As a bonus, this lets me write `this_sort_of_thing` without using the shift key.

My question is, from the Haskell programmers, whether using underscore in names is acceptable to the Haskell community or not. Is camelCase an unwritten rule or common convention? Would it be ok to make the public functions `likeThis` but internally write `like_this`?

Comment: You mean `likeThis`? `LikeThis` would be a constructor.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: @minitech, right, I made a mistake with the last one!

Comment: @gnat, I am aware of how stackexchange works. However, IIRC programmers.SE was founded for less-specific questions that programmers were still interested in which were not suitable for stackoverflow. Nevertheless, this question is opinion based if the answer is "it's up to you", but it's perfectly ok if the answer is "unwritten rule of international Haskell committee is to not use underscore". I wouldn't count this as opinion based. I didn't ask "do you like underscore?". I asked if the Haskell community accepts underscore. I'd try to put it in better wording still.

Comment: [Are you still confused about what Programmers is for?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5654/31260)

Comment: @gnat, [That's not what the actual users seem to think](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5676).

Comment: I think the only time I use snake casing in Haskell is for tuples. For example: `ints_bool = ([1,2,3], False)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s nothing particularly bad about using underscores in Haskell. One convention I have seen is to use `underscore_case` for local bindings and `camelCase` for top-level functions, or to prefix fields of a record with the record name and an underscore:

```
data These a = These { these_fooBar, these_barBaz :: a }
```

However, I prefer to use `camelCase` everywhere since it’s not worth fretting over, that’s what a majority of Haskell code is like, and it’s consistent with module names and constructors—unless you like `This_Sort_of_Thing`.

Comment: I just looked at how records work and ... good to know how the namespace problem is solved! Thanks for the answer. Also, `No_No_No_No_No`!

Comment: I've also seen `_ALLCAPS` for some constants defined with conditional compilation and the like.

Answer (score 6):

We conform to conventions and standards so that our code is intuitive for other programmers to work with.

```
private string _field;

public string Property { get; set; }

public void PublicMethod(string parameter)
{
    string localVariable;
}

private void privateMethod()
{

}
```

Most people that have been in a microsoft shop for a few years would be pretty familiar with this convention.

I wouldn't need to question the scope of _appleCore or AppleCore; I know _appleCore is a private field and AppleCore is a public property.

Part of your pride as a developer should be in how easily other people can understand and work with your code. Making ***maintainable*** and ***extensible*** code means making it maintainable/extensible for other people as well, not just ourselves.

As for the question about Haskall specifically:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_guidelines#Naming_Conventions

They have guidelines, but ultimately the owner of the codebase can define the convention as whatever they choose, that much isn't open for debate or question. Thus, this question you ask can't be answered definitely by us.

Comment: Props for talking about the importance of maintainable (readable) code.  Code is read more times than it is written.  This is exactly why it is important to follow the conventions of the community when writing your code.

Comment: @Shahbaz updated with a reference to Haskall's guidelines. Before your question you postulated that conventions are just a matter of style. To the owners of the codebase, this isn't always the case. They decide whether or not to allow freedom in convention, or to enforce conventions and standards.